# Least Square Estimate and Latent Space

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, latent-variable

I'm currently studying regression coefficient w.r.t latent space in a paper [Surprises in High-Dimensional Ridgeless Least Squares Interpolation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08560) by Trevor Hastie etc. This topic occurs in chapter 5.4 (page 16 ~). Let me write some parts of the chapters related to my question.

---

$\dots$ To motivate this example, assume that the responses $y_i$ are linear in the latent features vectors $z_i \in \mathbb R^d$. We do not observe this latent vector, but rather observe $p \ge d$ covariates $x_i := (x_{i,1},\dots,x_{i,p})$ that is also linear in the latent vector $z_i$:
$$y_i = \theta^T z_i + \zeta_i, \quad x_{i,j} = w_j^Tz_i+u_{i,j}.$$
Here, $\{\zeta_i\}_{1\le i \le n}$, and $\{u_{i,j}\}_{1\le i \le n, 1 \le j \le p}$ are noise variables that are mutually independent, and independent of $z_i$, with $\zeta_i \sim N(0, \sigma_{\zeta}^2),\ u_{i,j} \sim N(0,1)$. The features matrix takes the form $X = ZW^T + U$ and therefore, for $p > n$, **the min-norm regression ($l_2$ norm) amounts to**
$$\hat \beta = \underset{b}{\arg\min} \Bigl\{b : ZW^Tb + Ub = y \Bigr\} \tag1.$$

---

The features matrix can be obtained by letting
$$Z = \begin{bmatrix}
z_1^T\\
\vdots \\
z_n^T
\end{bmatrix}, \quad W^T =  \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \dots w_p\end{bmatrix}, \  \ [X]_{i,j} = x_{i,j}.$$

Now, this is where I'm stuck. We can obtain OLS estimator by
$$X^T(Y - Xb) = 0. \tag2$$
But the min-norm estimator above means $Xb = y$, and I'm not sure where this equation comes from. (It doesn't seem to come from OLS equation). Any hint for understanding (1) would be grateful. Thank you.

.

Comment: You might want to add more context to the question.  Section 5 is about "Misspecified Models" and the first sentence of section 5.4 is "We next consider an example in which \beta is aligned with the top eigenvectors of \Sigma".

Comment: I just omitted those because there is also $w_j$ representing misspecified ones, which seems different to the $w_j$ in my question. Using the same notation with different meaning would confuse readers as well as me. (Do you still suggest to add more information regarding the front part of section 5? or is my interpretation about $w_j$ wrong?)

Comment: it was a typo: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9481183/pdf/nihms-1830540.pdf, equation (1) should be '...=y', not '=0'

Comment: I see. Yet, I don't see how I obtain the $\hat \beta$. If $y - Xb$ comes from the above (2) equation, how can I delete $X^T$?

Comment: because they are considering the overparameterised case where the error is zero

Comment: Does the existence of $\zeta_i, \ u_{i,j}$ mean that there is an error? I can't get the meaning of "zero error" in section 5 clearly.